# Reading Chrome Frame Rate results in DevTools

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools, repaint, frame-rate

As far as I know the white (empty) bar represents idle time.
I know I should focus so that the application would run (at best) > 60fps and at least >30fps

This is my bar:
[image]

As you can see, I'm repainting on scroll ( changing the background position of an image ).
The middle line marks 60fps in this case, and if you pay attention closely, there is a top line (which is 30fps).

I've compared my results with others out there, and it seems that I have rather large idle times. Is that okay ? I know that paint, javascript and anything else is bad, but what purpose does displaying idle times serve ? Should I attempt to get rid of it, if so, what should I watch out for ?

Also, there is a spike every now and then because of "Image Decode", is there anything I can do about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Image Decode**

You can reduce the size of the image, which will make the decodes shorter. You can also trick the browser into doing these decodes earlier, perhaps at a time when there's no activity and therefore won't hurt your FPS.

I would also kill these big images temporarily to see if that moves you from 30fps to 60fps.

**Scroll handler**

You should minimize the amount of work you're doing in your scroll handler. At most you should be grabbing one scroll metric from the DOM and a timestamp perhaps. Then do your adjustments to style in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop: http://www.hesslerdesign.com/blog/javascript/optimizing-javascript-performance-handling-coordinate-updates/

**Heavy paints**

`background-position` isn't optimized well in WebKit or Blink, especially for this sort of usecase. I would put the image into a div and just slide its position using a `transform: translate(x,y)` (and promote it to its own layer if possible.) If sucessful, you won't repaint the entire screen on every scroll.

**30 FPS Aint bad**

A solid 30FPS actually looks better than something that's jumping between 60 and 45 all the time. Curious.. Are you in Canary or on a retina screen?

---

In general, you're doing pretty okay on your hardware, but I would try to reduce those image decodes. And you can go further with the above if you want.

Comment: The screenshot was taken on Stable Chrome 27 Macbook Pro OSX Lion.

The application actually (even as is) isn't that bad, but I'm trying to get a grasp of the Frame inspection tool. Still puzzled about the blank squares that represent idle time. Is idle bad, good, neutral ?

Comment: Would love for an edit to this answer to address the portion about idle time.